# Does shell maths run in a subshell?

Tags: shell, subshell, math

When I perform a simple math operation in `#!/bin/sh`, does that create a subshell?

E.g.,

```bsh
addition=$(( 1 + 1 ))
```

The syntax would suggest a subshell, but I couldn't find anything on this

Comment: No, it doesn't run in a subshell. `1 + 1` would not produce meaningful results if entered bare in a subshell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$(cmd arg)` runs `cmd` in a subshell environment and its output (minus the trailing newline characters), becomes the result of the expansion.

`(cmd arg)` does run in a subshell with its output unaffected.

So `$((cmd arg))` would be the same as `$(cmd arg)` but with an extra layer of subshell, except that it's not.

`$((...))` is a separate form of expansion that comes from the Korn shell. In the Korn shell, `((arithmetic expression))` evaluates the arithmetic expression (which follows a syntax very similar to that of C) and the exit status reflects whether the expression resolves to 0 or non-zero.

That allows things like:

```
if ((var < 10)); then
  ...
fi
```

Which makes it look very similar to `C`.

`$` is used to introduce *expansions*. Just like `$(cmd)` is like `(cmd)` except that it *expands* to the output of `cmd`, `$((arith))` is like `((arith))` except that it *expands* to the result of the evaluation of the arithmetic expression.

POSIX, whose `sh` is mostly based on ksh88, specified `$((...))` but not `((...))`. Actually, in an earlier draft, it was going for `$[...]` instead which is why you find that `bash` and `zsh` support `$[...]` as an alternative to `$((...))`.

IIRC, the main reason why POSIX initially thought of specifying it as `$[...]` is because `$((...))` conflicts with `$((cmd arg))`, a subshell inside a command substitution.

You'll find that most shells correctly identify `$((echo x; echo y) | (tr xy ab))` as *not* an arithmetic expansion, but not `$((cmd arg))`. In any case `$((cmd))` is meant to expand to the arithmetic value of the `$cmd` variable, not to the output of `cmd`.

The relevant text in the POSIX specification has:

> The syntax of the shell command language has an ambiguity for expansions beginning with "$((", which can introduce an arithmetic expansion or a command substitution that starts with a
>      subshell. Arithmetic expansion has precedence; that is, the shell shall first determine whether it can parse the expansion as an arithmetic expansion and shall only parse the expansion
>      as a command substitution if it determines that it cannot parse the expansion as an arithmetic expansion. The shell need not evaluate nested expansions when performing this
>      determination. If it encounters the end of input without already having determined that it cannot parse the expansion as an arithmetic expansion, the shell shall treat the expansion as
>      an incomplete arithmetic expansion and report a syntax error. A conforming application shall ensure that it separates the "$(" and '(' into two tokens (that is, separate them with white
>      space) in a command substitution that starts with a subshell. For example, a command substitution containing a single subshell could be written as:

`ksh`'s `((...))` also conflicts with nested subshells. While POSIX doesn't specify `((...))`, it does allow ksh's behaviour.

In practice, when nesting subshells and/or cmdsubsts, you should make sure to include white space between the parens:

```
echo "$( (...) )"
( (a; b) | (c;d) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a demo that it's *not* run in a subshell: you can modify variables in an arithmetic expression:

```bsh
$ x=5; echo "$(( x *= 2 ))"; echo "$x"
10
10
```

If it was a subshell, `echo $x` would output `5`.

When using shell arithmetic, beware that not all shells support pre- and post-increment; `dash` (the default `/bin/sh` in current versions of Debian and derivatives) will interpret `$(( ++i ))` as `$(( +(+i) ))` and NOT increment the `i` variable.