# What is the difference between $( (( expression )) ) and $((( expression )))?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why do they have different outputs?

```
echo $( (( 5+5 )) )

echo $((( 5+5 )))
10
```

Comment: Because they're different things. `$(...)` is a command substitution, and `$((...))` (without any space inside `$((` or `))`) is an arithmetic substitution. That's all explained in the manpage.

Comment: @mosvy What's not explained in the manual is why `$((( )))` is interpreted as `$(( () ))` rather than as `$( (()) )`. Maybe you could add that to a proper answer?

Comment: About the differences between `(`, `$(`, `((` and `$((`: [Does shell maths run in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565778/does-shell-maths-run-in-a-subshell/565787#565787)

Comment: @Kusalananda if bash was immediately treating `$(` as the start of a command substitution (without looking at the next character) there would be no way to write a arithm substitution using the `$((..))` syntax at all, since `$((` would never be considered. Feel free to add that to your A if you think this is the point of the Q. More interesting is how bash decides where an arithm subst has ended, since it obviously can't be the first `))`, or even the first unbalanced `))`. But there's no indication that the OP is interested in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$( (( 5+5 )) )` is the arithmetic expression `5+5` inside an [arithmetic compound commmand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) `(( … ))` inside a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) `$( … )`. The arithmetic compound command doesn't produce any output, so the result of the command substitution is empty. Arithmetic compound commands are only useful for assignments (this one doesn't have any assignment) or for their return value (which is not used here).

`$((( 5 + 5 )))` or `$(( ( 5+5 ) ))` is the arithmetic expression `( 5 + 5 )` inside an [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) `$(( … ))`. The result of the arithmetic expansion is the numerical value (formatted in decimal).

Answer (score 2):

Running the commands in `bash` with `set -x` enabled:

```
$ set -x
$ echo $( (( 5+5 )) )
++ ((  5+5  ))
+ echo

$ echo $((( 5+5 )))
+ echo 10
10
$ echo $(( ( 5+5 ) ))
+ echo 10
10
```

As you can see, the `$(...)` in the first command is taken as a command substitution.  This command substitution runs the command `((5+5))`.  This in turn is an arithmetic evaluation that does not have any output, so `echo` does not get any arguments and just outputs a newline.

In the other case (and in the extra case that I added), the `$((...))` is taken as an arithmetic expansion.  This computes the value of `(5+5)` and is replaced by the result of that computation.

To avoid confusion, I suggest that you use spaces to help the `bash` parser see what type of syntactic grouping that you want to use, like I showed in the last command above.